# Как составить многотабличный запрос SQLite Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Есть две таблицы, одна таблица содержит название наборов, вторая пары ключ = значение и колонку соответствия ключу одному из наборов. В обоих таблицах есть колонка, содержащая значение активности набора и активности пары соответственно (is_it_used = 1 (входит в выборку) or = 0 (не входит в выборку)). Как то так...

[image: Таблицы]

Нужен запрос который бы соединял две таблицы и выводил список ключей упуская неактивные наборы и неактивные ключи. SQL-запрос выглядит как-то так:

```
SELECT keys.key, keys.value
FROM set, keys
WHERE set._id = keys.set_id AND set.is_it_used = 1 AND keys.is_it_used = 1;
```

Как этот вопрос заложить в приложение через метод (если этот метод тут вообще можно использовать, конечно):

```
public Cursor query( Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder );
```

Или может быть это можно как-то сделать по другому? подскажите, кто знает.

В приложении есть ContractClass который ассоциирует URI с таблицами.

Comment: а вы уверены, что это рабочий запрос? Мне кажется, запросы к нескольким таблицам можно делать только через `JOIN`, разве нет? Еще можно конечно сделать вложенный запрос...  А по поводу вашего вопроса - есть метод `rawQuery`, который принимает любой запрос в виде `String`

Comment: @metalurgus Ну запрос написан правильно. В большинстве СУБД  оператор `,` в from аналогичен оператору join

Comment: записать запрос можно и так:    select keys.key, keys.value from set join keys on set._id = keys.set_id where set.is_it_used = 1 and keys.is_it_used = 1;     смысл не в запросе, а как этот запрос реализовать через androidSDK

Comment: @ЕвгенийКузнецов, ок, не знал, что так можно... Сейчас ответ оформлю по поводу запроса текстового.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКузнецов при формировании запроса к выборке из двух таблиц, тут только rawQuery()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам, судя по всему, нужен метод [rawQuery](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])). Пример:

```
    String sqlQuery = "SELECT keys.key, keys.value "
                      + "FROM set, keys "
                      + "WHERE set._id = keys.set_id AND set.is_it_used = 1 AND keys.is_it_used = 1;";
       Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);
```